# Dynamic mv command from shell script doesn't appear to be working when spaces are in the file names

Tags: shell, sh, mv

I have been searching for several hours now, but can't seem to find an answer to this. I am attempting to create a shell script in a FreeNAS 11 jail (freebsd) that will move some files into a sub folder. I have it getting the paths correctly, but when it comes time to move the files over, it doesn't work (when the file name contains spaces).

```
#!/bin/sh

# Primary dir to scan
SRC_DIR=/mnt/transcode/batch/
WORKING_DIR="${SRC_DIR}working/"

for FILE in $SRC_DIR*
do

    # only run against files...
    if test -f "${FILE}"
    then
        #FILE_NAME=$(basename "$FILE" | sed 's/ /\\ /g') # replace spaces with escaped space
        #mv "$SRC_DIR""$FILE_NAME" "$WORKING_DIR""$FILE_NAME"
        #mv $SRC_DIR$FILE_NAME $WORKING_DIR$FILE_NAME

        FILE_NAME=$(basename "$FILE")
        mv \""$SRC_DIR""$FILE_NAME"\" \""$WORKING_DIR""$FILE_NAME"\" #wrap each parameter in double quotes

        # copying this output back into terminal works
        #echo mv \""$SRC_DIR""$FILE_NAME"\" \""$WORKING_DIR""$FILE_NAME"\"
    fi

done
```

The above code also contains a few extra things that I have tried as well.

I get the following message when running the script

```
mv: rename "/mnt/transcode/batch/REDACTED FILE NAME.mkv" to "/mnt/transcode/batch/working/REDACTED FILE NAME.mkv": No such file or directory
```

The thing that is interesting is that when I take the output of `echo mv \""$SRC_DIR""$FILE_NAME"\" \""$WORKING_DIR""$FILE_NAME"\"` and paste it back into terminal it will execute perfectly fine.

I am running this via SSH as root. Destination folder permissions are `drwxrwxr-x+`

I am running my script via `./test.sh` (as root user)

Is there another way to do this, or is there a problem with my script?

Any help is appreciated.

PS There is no /bin/bash in my jail, not sure if that makes a difference.

--Edit--

Here is the (hopefully) final code that I want to execute:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Primary dir to scan
SRC_DIR=/mnt/transcode/batch/
DEST_DIR="${SRC_DIR}converted/"
WORKING_DIR="${SRC_DIR}working/"
DONE_DIR="${SRC_DIR}orginal/"

# only get files, not directories
#for FILE in `ls -p $SRC_DIR | grep -v /`
for FILE in $SRC_DIR*
do

    # only run against files...
    if test -f "${FILE}"
    then
        FILE_NAME=$(basename "$FILE" | sed 's/ /\\ /g')

        # move the file to the working dir
        mv $SRC_DIR$FILE_NAME $WORKING_DIR$FILE_NAME

        # vars for later
        MEDIA_FILE=$WORKING_DIR$FILE_NAME

        # Get some into about the current file
        AUDIO_CODEC="$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=s=x:p=0 $MEDIA_FILE)"
        MEDIA_INFO="$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width -of csv=s=x:p=0 $MEDIA_FILE)"
        VIDEO_HEIGHT="$(echo "$MEDIA_INFO" | cut -d 'x' -f2)"
        VIDEO_WIDTH="$(echo "$MEDIA_INFO" | cut -d 'x' -f1)"

        # start up handbrake
        HandBrakeCLI -i $WORKING_DIR$FILE_NAME -o $DEST_DIR${FILE_NAME%.*}.mkv -f av_mkv -m -e x264 -q 22 --vfr --audio-lang-list eng -E copy:$AUDIO_CODEC --crop 0:0:0:0 -w $VIDEO_WIDTH -l $VIDEO_HEIGHT --subtitle-lang-list eng

        # move the file to the done dir
        mv $WORKING_DIR$FILE_NAME $DONE_DIR$FILE_NAME
    fi

done
```

The eventual goal is to move a single file to a working directory, while is is being transcoded, then move it out do a done folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the extra quotes you're adding to the filenames.

```
mv \"foo\" bar
```

tries to rename a file literally called `"foo"` (including quotes).

Also, don't use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for your variables. `ALL_UPPERCASE` is used by the system (e.g. `HOME`) or the shell itself (e.g. `RANDOM`, `PWD`).

I'd do it like this:

```
src_dir=/mnt/transcode/batch
working_dir="$src_dir/working"

for file in "$src_dir"/*; do
    # only run against files...
    if test -f "$file"; then
        mv -- "$file" "$working_dir/"
    fi
done
```

You can `mv` directly into a directory, no need to extract the basename first.

---

Untested, but here's the rest of your script. I've added the missing quotes, removed the weird backslash additions, etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Primary dir to scan
src_dir=/mnt/transcode/batch
dest_dir="$src_dir/converted"
working_dir="$src_dir/working"
done_dir="$src_dir/orginal"

for src_file in "$src_dir"/*; do
    if test -f "${src_file}"; then
        basename="${src_file##*/}"
        working_file="$working_dir/$basename"

        # move the file to the working dir
        mv -- "$src_file" "$working_file"

        # Get some into about the current file
        audio_codec="$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=s=x:p=0 "$working_file")"
        media_info="$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width -of csv=s=x:p=0 "$working_file")"
        video_height="${media_info#*x}"
        video_width="${media_info%%x*}"

        # start up handbrake
        HandBrakeCLI -i "$working_file" -o "$dest_dir/${basename%.*}.mkv" -f av_mkv -m -e x264 -q 22 --vfr --audio-lang-list eng -E copy:"$audio_codec" --crop 0:0:0:0 -w "$video_width" -l "$video_height" --subtitle-lang-list eng

        # move the file to the done dir
        mv -- "$working_file" "$done_dir/"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Ahh, didn't see this before I posted some extra details. I just tested it and it works as a stand alone script. I will see if I can incorporate this into my larger script.

Comment: Yes! Thank you soo much @melpomene - now I just need to study it and figure out where I went wrong